# Entity Framework query custom object

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to query something like this:

```
var values = new Entities().result.SqlQuery( 
"select distinct     
i.item_type_id,     
Min(value) over (partition by i.item_type_id) as min,     
Max(value) over (partition by i.item_type_id) as max,     
Avg(value) over (partition by i.item_type_id) as avg    
from items i   
inner join packages p on p.id = i.package_id " 
WHERE ... ").ToList();
```

First I tried `var values = new Entities().item.SqlQuery(...)`
but the result has nothing to do with item, item has different properties from the result of this query.

Than I created result object:

```
public partial class rolling_table
{
    public int item_type_id { get; set; }
    public int min { get; set; }
    public int max { get; set; }
    public int avg { get; set; }
}
```

and run `var values = new Entities().result.SqlQuery()`

But it is complaining that

> The entity type result is not part of the model for the current
>   context.

I guess it thinks result is a table in the database, however it is not.

How can I query custom type, not persistent objects ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `SqlQuery` method on the `Database` object.

```
var values = context.Database.SqlQuery<rolling_table>("your_query").ToList();
```